# How to add optional chaining to strings with brackets access in js?

Tags: javascript, regex

I create this regex to add optional chaining (?.) in the string: `/(?<=\w+\.)(\w+)\.(?!\?)/g`.

This regex works fine for property access with dot notation. for example `foo.bar.baz` will transform to `foo?.bar?.baz`.

But I want also to support property with brackets `foo.bar[0].baz`.

So I change the regex to have `.` or `[`: `/(?<=\w+\.)(\w+)\.|\[(?!\?)/g` but the replace remove the `[` char.

Is it possible to change the regex so it match and replace also properties with brackets?

```js
const inputs = [
  'foo.bar',        // foo?.bar
  'foo.bar.baz',    // foo?.bar?.baz
  'foo.bar.baz.go', // foo?.bar?.baz?.go
  'foo[0].bar',     // foo?.[0]?.bar
  'foo.bar[0]',     // foo?.bar?.[0]
  'foo.bar[0].bla', // foo?.bar?.[0]?.bla
  'foo',            // foo
  'foo.bar[text].some.bla[0]', // foo?.bar?.[text]?.some?.bla?.[0]
  "foo?.you['text'][text].some[0].bla", // foo.you?.['text']?.[text]?.some?.[0]?.bla
];

const regex = /(?<=\w+\.)(\w+)\.(?!\?)/g;
const outputs = inputs.map((input) => input.replace(regex, '$1?.'));
console.log(outputs);
```

Comment: Add `(?:\[\d+])?`, like in `/(?<=\w+\.)(\w+(?:\[\d+])?)\.(?!\?)/g`?

Comment: I try but it's not enough because it not match `foo[0].bar` or `foo.bar[0]` and sometimes it can number or string or any word there with + logic or ` char

Comment: My mistake. should be `foo?.bar`.

Comment: Try `const regex = /\b\.(?=(?!\?))|(?<=[\]\w])(?=\[)|(?<=])\./g;` and then `inputs.map((input) => input.replace(regex, '?.'))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it do it right. can you please explain this regex?

Comment: Posted as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75545201/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
const inputs = [
  'foo.bar',        // foo?.bar
  'foo.bar.baz',    // foo?.bar?.baz
  'foo.bar.baz.go', // foo?.bar?.baz?.go
  'foo[0].bar',     // foo?.[0]?.bar
  'foo.bar[0]',     // foo?.bar?.[0]
  'foo.bar[0].bla', // foo?.bar?.[0]?.bla
  'foo',            // foo
  'foo.bar[text].some.bla[0]', // foo?.bar?.[text]?.some?.bla?.[0]
  "foo?.you['text'][text].some[0].bla", // foo.you?.['text']?.[text]?.some?.[0]?.bla
];

const regex = /(?<=[a-z_])\.(?!\?)|(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=\[)|(?<=])\./gi;
const outputs = inputs.map((input) => input.replace(regex, '?.'));
console.log(outputs);
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<=[a-z_])` - immediately before the current location, there must be an ASCII letter or underscore
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?!\?)` - not immediately followed with a `?` char
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[\]a-z_])(?=\[)` - a position between `]`, underscore or an ASCII letter char and a `[` char
- `|` - or
- `(?<=])\.` - a `.` that is immediately preceded with a `.` char.

Comment: I found that the input `1.2` transform to `1?.2`. is there a way to do it only to words or chars?

Comment: @JonSud I removed the `\d` from `\w`-related subpatterns.

Comment: @jabaa Of course, it won't. It is not meant to. It is only meant to work with string type described in `const inputs`.

Comment: @jabaa Let's focus on the current requirements. Once OP changes them, I will adjust.

Comment: @jabaa Because they are deduced from the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to identify string literals and decimal points so to avoid replacing things that should stay.

Below is a much longer regex that will identify string literals, decimal points, and insertion points just before a `[`.

I modified and added some more challenging test cases:

```js
const inputs = [
  'foo.bar',
  'foo.bar.baz',
  'foo.bar.baz?.go',
  'foo[0].bar',
  'foo.bar[0]',
  'foo.bar[0].bla',
  'foo',
  'foo.bar[text].some.bla[0]',
  "foo.you['tex.t']['t[ext'].some?.[0].bla",
  "foo[2.][9e1]",
  "2.3.toFixed?.['.']",
  "+1_2..toFixed",
  "'ab][c.'.toUpperCase",
  "foo.[']'].$$$._",
];

const regex = /(\[?(?:(['"`])(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*\2|\.(?=[\d.[\]])|[^'"`?.[])+)(?=[?.[])\??\.?/g;
const outputs = inputs.map((input) => input.replace(regex, '$1?.'));
console.log(outputs);
```

The first (large) capture group matches text that needs to remain unaltered:

- `` (['"`])(?:\\.|(?!\2).)*\2 ``  matches a string literal that takes into account that a backslash is an escape character, so the character that follows it should not be taken as string delimiter. The group `` (['"`]) `` is the second group in the overal regex, so the closing delimiter is matched with `\2`.
- `\.(?=[\d.[\]])` matches a decimal point when it cannot be interpreted as a property accessor point.
- `` [^'"`?.[] `` matches any character of `` '"`?.[ ``. This restriction is to avoid that during backtracking the previous options would be given up in favor of this one.
- `(?:  |   |   )+` repeats matching the above options as long as possible. This part of the match will stop at either the end of the input, or just before a `.`, a `?` or a `[`. (A quote could also be possible, but then the input is malformed)

After that first capture group has been matched, we are at a potential insertion point of `?.`. But it should not be inserted when at the end of the input, so we have this assertion:

- `(?=[?.[])` requires that a character must still follow (so not at the end of the input) which must be one of `?.[`. This requirement also avoids backtracking to an invalid insertion position.

Then the insertion point has been reached:

- `\??\.?` matches the characters (if any) that need to be removed before inserting `?.`. Note that this also matches `?.`, which results in a replacement of itself.

The replacement is:

- `$1` to reproduce what was captured in the first (large) capture group
- `?.` to insert the optional chaining operator character combination.